# Problem requesting data based on URL parameters in React-Redux

Tags: node.js, express, react-redux, mern

On a MERN-stack application, I would like to request data from a particular user's schema based on the url parameters. For instance, http://localhost:3000/user/User1 would render data from User 1. I am using redux-react for state management. Here is what I currently have, and here is what's happening.

**Userpage Component**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {getUser} from '../../actions/userActions'; 
import {connect} from 'react-redux'

class Userpage extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
      getUser(this.props.match.params.username)
 }

  render() {
    return (
     <div>
         <h1>Hello</h1>
         <h3>{this.props.user.name}</h3>
         <h3>{this.props.user.email}</h3>
     </div>
    );
  }
}


const mapStatetoProps = state => {
    return{user: state.user}
}; 

export default connect(mapStatetoProps, getUser) (Userpage)
```

**userActions**

```
import axios from 'axios'; 
import {GET_USER} from './types'; 

export const getUser = username => dispatch => {
    axios
    .get(`/api/users/${username}`)
    .then(({res}) => 
        dispatch({
            type: GET_USER, 
            payload: username
        })
    )
};
```

**userReducer**

```
import { GET_USER } from "../actions/types";

const initialState = {
  user: {}, 
};

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_USER:
      return{
        ...state,
        user: action.payload, 
      }
}
```

Then in the api/users route, I have the following:

```
router.get("/:username", (req, res) => {
  User.findOne({username: req.params.username})
  .then(user => res.json(user))
});
```

Beyond the user state returning as empty, here are some errors I am getting.
On the command line, I occasionally get a

> Could not proxy request /api/users/function%20(action)%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(typeof%20action%20===%20'function')%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20action(dispatch,%20getState,%20extraArgument);%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20next(action);%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:5000.

As well as a

> mapDispatchToProps() in Connect(Userpage) must return a plain object. Instead received undefined.

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what is your `this.props.match.params.username`? can you console log? It seems to be a function. Also, `Userpage` is under react router right?

Comment: @atriachakraborty If I have username = this.props.match.params.username I can  console.log(username) and get the query string and get "User1" in this case.

Comment: and inside the `getUser` function? can you console log username there as well?

Comment: This is what I end up getting if I log inside the getUser function: 
`userActions.js:5 ƒ (action) {
        if (typeof action === 'function') {
          return action(dispatch, getState, extraArgument);
        }

        return next(action);
      }`
Not sure exactly what's going on here, but I suspect it has to do with the problem.